# Spring Data Jpa: persisting child entities from parent entity does not update child identity

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Environment:

- OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Java: OpenJDK 17.0.3
- Spring Boot: 2.6.7
- MySQL: 8.0.29

Is it normal for Spring Data Jpa (or Jpa in general) to **NOT** update child identity attributes when the child is persisted (saved) via the parent entity repository?

Consider this:

```
@Entity( name = "Company" )
@Table( name = "COMPANY" )
final public class Company
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
  @Column( name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false )
  private Long id = null;

  @OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "company",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
  )
  private Set< Phone > phoneSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();

  ...getters/setters...
}

@Entity( name = "Phone" )
@Table( name = "PHONE" )
final public class Phone
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
  @Column( name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false )
  private Long id = null;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn( name = "COMPANY_ID" )
  private Company company = null;

  @Column( name = "number" )
  String number = null;

  ...getters/setters...
}


private void someClassFunction()
{
  .....
  Phone phone = new Phone( company, "1115551234" );
  company.getPhoneSet().add( phone );
  this.companyRespository.save( company );  // <<<< NOTE THIS LINE
  System.out.println( "phone.id: " + phone.getId() );
}
```

When I call *someClassFunction()* I get:

```
phone.id: null
```

The database assigned **id** is NOT available to me immediately. I did check the database and the record was inserted (persisted/saved) and MySQL did assign an ID. If I reload the parent class (company) in another function, the child is reloaded and has the correct id.

However, if I modify *someClassFunction()* to this:

```
private void someClassFunction()
{
  .....
  Phone phone = new Phone( company, "1115551234" );
  company.getPhoneSet().add( phone );
  this.phoneRespository.save( phone );  // <<<< NOTE THIS LINE
  System.out.println( "phone.id: " + phone.getId() );
}
```

and then call *someClassFunction()* I get:

```
phone.id: 47
```

The database assigned **id** is available to me immediately.

I don't find the parent/child persist (ie: *this.companyRespository.save( company )* ) behavior disclosed in any online documentation or tutorials. I am led to believe that persisting from the parent should work the same as persisting the child directly ( ie: *this.phoneRespository.save( phone )* ).

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have an incorrect entity definition?

Comment: I think you would need to print the elements of `company.getPhoneSet()` to get the phone ids. Could also be an issue with your `@Transactional` annotation and where it is

Comment: Not sure I understand your suggestion to print the elements. I fail to see how that would make a difference. I'm not using any `@Transactional` annotations at this time.

Comment: Difference being that `this.companyRespository.save( company );` updates the company object and most probably replaces `company.getPhoneSet()` with a new collection. This collection would contain the phone added previously, but not update the phone instance. That is also the reason it works in the second example. You update the phone instance directly and don't care about the company instance

Comment: in case one you should add `phone.setCompany(company);` in order to `COMPANY_ID` points to company. is `companyRespository` a custom implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected - check the contract on your 'save' method. It returns an instance which may be a copy of the one you passed in, and it is this instance you need to check and use - it will have its identity set when the entityManager is synchronized with the database (on transaction commit, or if the EntityManager is flushed).

ie

```
  Phone phone = new Phone( company, "1115551234" );
  company.getPhoneSet().add( phone );
  phone.setCompany(company);//Don't forget to set this!
  Company mergedCompanyInstance = this.companyRespository.save( company );
  Phone managedPhone = mergedCompanyInstance.getPhoneSet().get(0);//assuming you have only one in the set, otherwise, check by phone number.
  System.out.println( "phone.id: " + phone.getId() );
  System.out.println( "managedPhone.id: " + managedPhone.getId() );
```

Spring does some internal checks in the save method to determine if it should call JPA EntityManager merge or persist api. If it calls merge, it returns the managed entity instance from the context (which may be a clone of the one you give it) while if it calls persist, it takes your instance and causes it to become managed. It is the managed instance that is returned on any findById and query methods.

Comment: Thank you. This indeed seems to be the behavior. But isn't `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` suppose to perform the merge to avoid this behavior?

Comment: Merge is cascading, which is the issue. You have an existing entity, which causes Spring to use merge and the contract on that is that it returns 'the' managed instance - so it reads it in from the DB and merges your changes into that copy. For a new Phone, because it cascades the merge operation, it has to make a copy as well to keep the models consistent. Persist is often used for new entities, which avoids this overhead, as what you stick in is what is used as the managed instance. Spring's save is just doing the choice for you.